# Does the threading.Event() object suffer from spurious wakeup?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, blocking, spurious-wakeup

In C, pthread condition variables serve the same purpose as `threading.Event()` variables in python. My question is, do `threading.Event()` variables suffer from the same spurious wakeup issues as pthread condition variables?